# NodeMCU ESP8266 WiFi low RF power level

Tags: lua, esp8266, nodemcu

I tested the NodeMCU firmware on 4 ESP8266 modules and I have a problem with the WiFi range of the modules (only 8 meters).

I tried to switch to the Arduino ESP8266 core firmware and voilà, the modules have a better range (>12 meters). I think that NodeMCU doesn't set the ESP8266 to the maximum power.

I looked at the Arduino code and it contains a `setOutputPower` method that set the RF power level of the ESP8266. How can I set this option in the  NodeMCU firmware without modifying the firmware?

Comment: A valid question for Stack Overflow - it's about programming Arduino and/or NodeMCU Lua.

Comment: Just updated my answer as new PR will improve the API.

Comment: I don't understand the downvote. I went crazy on the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Higher RF power level means higher power consumption obviously. You need to balance your options should you run the device off a battery.

NodeMCU offers `wifi.setphymode()` to control this. The [documentation](http://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/latest/en/modules/wifi/#wifisetphymode) gives you a nice overview how the pyh mode relates to typical power consumption.

**Update 2017-11-19**

There's a PR in the making that'll give you control over `system_phy_set_max_tpw` from the SDK: https://github.com/nodemcu/nodemcu-firmware/pull/2171